# How to chain a vb.net null coalesce operator?

Tags: vb.net

I have a class Customer which contains the property Extensions which in turn contains the property Any.

I tried to do:

```
Dim room  = If(customer.Extensions.Any.ElementAt(0).InnerText, Nothing)
```

but it threw an error when it did not find an Extension element in the incoming xml.  I thought it would return nothing once it saw that the first expression was Nothing.  Do I have to do a multiple if statement in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do have to check for at least one element. So what you could do would be:

```
Dim a = customer.Extensions.Any.FirstOrDefault()
Dim room = If(a Is Nothing, Nothing, a.InnerText)
```

Depending on the type of `customer.Extensions.Any`, you could do this:

```
Dim room = If(customer.Extensions.Any.Count > 0, customer.Extensions.Any(0), Nothing)
```

Comment: ok, I will give it a try.  In your first example, are you using LINQ and will Any(0) return the InnerText?

Comment: Also, for the first and second example, doesn't it have to be IIf?

Comment: @Xaisoft: Yes, I'm using link. And no, Any(0) will cause an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. And in the second example, no it doesn't. The `If()` operator replaced the legacy `IIf()` *function* in VB 2008. `If()` isn't "null coalesce" as far as I know, it's inline conditional.

Comment: customer is a class, Extensions is class, and Any is a class, so I guess I couldn't do the second part because I would assume it would throw a null reference exception if any of those was null along the way.

Comment: @minitech `If(x, y)` is the "null coalesce" operator. It's the same as `If(x IsNot Nothing, x, y)`.

Comment: @MarkHurd: Yep. Aah. 2011 :D